# copying a number to another file on new line

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed

I have some questions concerning a shell script I have a problem with on my Linux system.

```
newseed=$((1 + RANDOM*RANDOM % 2147483647))
sed -i -e '14c\seed="'"$newseed"'"' /home/rustserver/lgsm/config-lgsm/rustserver/common.cfg
```

I would like `newseed=$` to copy a number from a file called seeds.txt that i would increment myself but everytime it copies a seed, it has to go on a new line and copy new seeds to avoid duplicates. (A seed is like this
287222495).

How could I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Copy what number? From what file? Copy it to where? Please [edit] your question and add an example input and your desired output so we can understand what you need.

Comment: Thanks terdon, editing it now.